# source data from syslog into flume

Tags: flume, syslog

I tried to setup a flume agent to source data from syslog server.
basically, I have setup a syslog server on an server so-called (server1) to receive syslog events, then forward all messages to different server (server2) where the flume agent installed, then finally all data will be sink to kafka cluster.

Flume configuration as below.

```
# For each one of the sources, the type is defined
agent.sources.syslogSrc.type = syslogudp
agent.sources.syslogSrc.port = 9090
agent.sources.syslogSrc.host = server2

# The channel can be defined as follows.
agent.sources.syslogSrc.channels = memoryChannel

# Each channel's type is defined.
agent.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory

# Other config values specific to each type of channel(sink or source)
# can be defined as well
# In this case, it specifies the capacity of the memory channel
agent.channels.memoryChannel.capacity = 100


# config for kafka sink
agent.sinks.kafkaSink.channel = memoryChannel
agent.sinks.kafkaSink.type = org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
agent.sinks.kafkaSink.kafka.topic = flume
agent.sinks.kafkaSink.kafka.bootstrap.servers = <kafka.broker.list>:9092
agent.sinks.kafkaSink.kafka.flumeBatchSize = 20
agent.sinks.kafkaSink.kafka.producer.acks = 1
agent.sinks.kafkaSink.kafka.producer.linger.ms = 1
agent.sinks.kafkaSink.kafka.producer.compression.type = snappy
```

But, somehow logsys is not getting injected into flume agent.

appricate for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

> I have setup a syslog server on an server so-called (server1)

The `syslogudp` Source must bind to `server1` host

```
agent.sources.syslogSrc.host = server1
```

> then forward all messages to different server (server2)

the different server refers to the Sink

```
agent.sinks.kafkaSink.kafka.bootstrap.servers = server2:9092
```

Flume agent is only a process that hosts these components (Source, Sink, Channel) to facilitate the flow of events.

Comment: hi @franklinsijo, i have tried to change to server address and  got following exception.

org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: ldndsr000004895/10.75.24.139:9090

Comment: Is the port in `LISTEN` state in that host? Can you try `netstat -napl | grep 9090` on server1 to check the status of the port?

Comment: Rsyslog in the `LISTEN` already 
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9090                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      37971/rsyslogd` @franklinsijo

Comment: this is `syslogtcp`!!

Comment: both UDP and TCP are listening on same port bro.
`udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9090                0.0.0.0:*                               37971/rsyslogd`
just forget coping @franklinsijo

Comment: Ah okay, can you check the complete stacktrace to look for the `Caused By:`, the  cause for ChannelException